# Integration by substituiton troubles

Tags: calculus

For a physics problem, I did change of variables like so (setting $u=l+d-x$):
$$\int_0^l \frac{x}{(l+d-x)^2} dx = \int_{l+d}^d \frac{l+d-u}{u^2} dx$$

Now this is clearly wrong, because they turn out to have different signs (and this is obvious since if $d$ and $l$ are positive, the left integral sweeps to the right and the right - to the left). I've made some stupid mistake in reasoning, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: On the right-hand side, you should be integrating w.r.t. $du = -dx$.

Comment: You're most certainly right. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.

Comment: So are you still having trouble or no?

Comment: No, my mistake was pointed out to me.